# Count and add columns for each value in a group

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a mysql table. I want to group by name and get column for each "Type" exists on each group (for the same name). In additional I want to add column says how many times most common value (highest one if exist) in the same group and column with value of the most common value and how many unique types.

Example of my table

```
  |  Type | Name        |
  |  Y    | Bike        |
  |  Y    | Bike        |
  |  X    | Bike        |
  |  X    | Bike        |
  |  XX   | Car         |
  |  ZZ   | Car         |
  |  L    | Boat        |
  |  ZZ   | Car         |
  |  ZZ   | Car         |
  |  ZZ   | Bike        |
  |  P    | Boat        |
  |  P    | Boat        |
```

Example of results I want to get

```
  | Name        | Type1 | Type2 | Type3 | MostCommon | MostCommonCount | UniqueType      |
  | Bike        | Y     | X     | ZZ    |            |                 | 3               |
  | Car         | XX    | ZZ    |       |    ZZ      |        3        | 2               |
  | Boat        | P     | L     |       |    P       |        2        | 2               |
```

Comment: Why is 'Y' type1 ? And are you sure that you want to resolve issues of data display (typically, a presentation layer problem), in MySQL?

Comment: It can be Type2 or Type3 its just give column for every unique type should be incremental Type count TypeX, I must solve it in mysql because my framework use a query as a data provider.

Comment: You can't have a dynamic number of columns for a query.

Comment: For the example I can use static of 3 columns

Comment: So which 3? And what have you tried? Review GROUP BY for adding up; HAVING... LIMIT 1 to get the highest value. And DISTINCT for unique types. But I'm with @Strawberry - the best way to do this would be to run multiple queries from inside something like PHP and use it to create the output formatting. Good luck.

Comment: You can have a dynamic number of columns in a query but it requires a sproc and a prepared statement. Compared with alternatives, it's tedious.